# Keyboard shortcut to shutdownPC in lubuntu desktop 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, lubuntu

I have recently installed **lubuntu-desktop** metapackage in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. But in **lubuntu** I can't find any keyboard shortcut to shutdown or logout [in **Unity** or **Gnome** I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> but now it opens **Task manager**]. Can anyone please provide me keyboard shortcuts to these commands. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this help: http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=31648#p38803 ?

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes it worked. The command given by author[`lxsession-logout`] dosen't show **lubuntu logo**. Fortunately there is a predefined command[`lubuntu-logout`] which logs you out when you press your PCs **Poweroff** button. I copied that code and changed the _Keybind-key_ to `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question, Thaks to [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) for useful link.

### These are the steps to follow ([source](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=31648#p38803)):-

1. Go to `~/.config/openbox/` and open the file **lubuntu-rc.xml** from any text-editor[such as `leafpad`].
2. Find the keyboard area to set hot keys. It's between the markers `<keyboard>` and `</keyboard>`.
3. Add following code after at last [before `<mouse>`]:

   Change `C-End` with your *keybind-key*[*C* for `Ctrl`, *A* for `Alt`]

   ```
   <keybind key="C-End">
   <action name="Execute">
   <command>lubuntu-logout</command>
   </action>
   </keybind>
   ```
4. Save the file.
5. Log-out and Log-in back.
6. Now you can use defined key to logout/ shutdown/ restart, etc.